# Nuxt js is not loading images when switched to production environment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on an app quite a big one to be honest. When I was working on the development environment everything was working well no errors or anything like that. Now I switched to the production environment I'm getting a lot of errors. Nuxt is not loading some images for some reason. I have my images stored under `assets/**/*`.

Image import example:

```
<img :src="require(~/assets/establishment_img/${image})" alt="preview image">
```

here's the errors:
[image]

nuxt-config.js

```
const path = require("path")

export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: "Estudiant Orientation",
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: "en"
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      { hid: "description", name: "description", content: "" }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        type: "text/css",
        href:
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
      }, // font-awesome css
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        type: "text/css",
        href:
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.4.15/swiper-bundle.css"
      }, // swiper css
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        type: "text/css",
        href:
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
      }, // animate css
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        type: "text/css",
        href:
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/10.15.5/sweetalert2.min.css"
      } // sweetalert2 css
    ],
    script: [
      {
        hid: "stripe",
        src:
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.4.15/swiper-bundle.min.js",
        defer: true
      }, // swiper js
      {
        hid: "stripe",
        src:
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/10.15.5/sweetalert2.all.js",
        defer: true
      }, // sweetalert2 js
      {
        hid: "stripe",
        src:
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js",
        defer: true
      }, // chart js
      {
        hid: "stripe",
        src: "https://unpkg.com/vue-chartjs/dist/vue-chartjs.min.js",
        defer: true
      }, // vue-chart js
      {
        hid: "stripe",
        src: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.0/gsap.min.js",
        defer: true
      }, // gsap js
      {
        hid: "stripe",
        src:
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollTrigger/1.0.5/ScrollTrigger.min.js",
        defer: true
      }, // ScrollTrigger js
      {
        hid: "stripe",
        src: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/108/three.min.js",
        defer: true
      } // three js
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    "~/assets/css/global.css",
    "~/assets/css/animations.css",
    "~/assets/css/variables.css",
    "~/assets/css/dashboard-light.css",
    "~/assets/css/modal.css",
    "~/node_modules/vue-select/dist/vue-select.css"
  ],

  // Global JS
  js: [
    "~/node_modules/trading-vue-js/dist/trading-vue.min.js",
    "~/assets/js/hover-effect.umd.js" // distortion hover effect js
  ],

  //router active links
  router: {
    linkActiveClass: '--do-nothing',
    linkExactActiveClass: 'active',
  },

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: "~/plugins/_globals.js" },
    { src: "~/plugins/vue-chartkick.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: '~/plugins/vuex-persist.js', ssr: false},
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/bootstrap
    "bootstrap-vue/nuxt",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt",
    "@nuxtjs/bootstrap-vue",
  ],

  bootstrapVue: {
    bootstrapCSS: false,
    bootstrapVueCSS: false
  },

  // Specifying the build directory
  buildDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "../server/public"),

  // environment proxy
  proxy: {
    "/api": {
      target: "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  },

  router: {
    middleware: ["user-auth"]
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {}
};
```

also this is what I do in my index.js for the server side:

```
// Handling Production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Static Folder
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

    // Handle SPA
    app.get(/.*/, (req, res) => res.send(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
}
```

Is there a way to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please show how you import/use your images in your code

Comment: everything is dynamic so here's an example `<img :src="require(`~/assets/establishment_img/${image}`)" alt="preview image">`

Comment: Try to add ~@/assets.... or without ~

Comment: What are your `target`, `spa` keys in your `nuxt.config.js`? How do you build your app and where do you host it?

Comment: Your server is misconfigured

Comment: I'm uploading my nuxt-config file

Comment: is there something wrong with my configuration @Areg?

Comment: @SaboSuke what are you using Nginx?

Comment: No, I'm not using it. To be honest I wanted to use it but I had problems with it along the way didn't really know how to use it correctly so I decided not to. Also I'm using windows so it's kind of harder to use it.

Comment: @SaboSuke since `/` takes to the static folder you need to find a way somehow to take it to the actual _nuxt folder instead

Answer (score -4):

It's not necessary to use `require(~/assets/establishment_img/${image})` construction in your nuxt.js app!

You can just put your static image inside /static/ folder at your nuxt project root and access it in your app using:

```
<img :src="`/establishment_img/${image}`" alt="preview image">
```

So it will be both available in dev and production modes

Comment: You're wrong it's necessary  to use require because as I said above it's dynamic it will not work if it's not wrapped in require

Comment: On top of the fact that placing the image in `public` is not always the best solution. Indeed, `assets` is preferred.

Comment: Well in that case you can create an alias for assets folder in your nuxt.config.js, something like: 

`
build: {
        extend(config, ctx) {
            config.resolve.alias['~assets'] = path.resolve(__dirname, './assets')
        }
    }
`
And then do require(~assets/establishment_img/${image})

Comment: I don't know why this happened. But, I just did some modifications and rebuilt the app. I run in production mode and everything seems to be working fine this time??? This is confusing sometimes it works and some other times it just doesn't...